# Bigquery query - doing event counts on subselects for grouped data

Tags: google-bigquery

A colleague asked to pull some data about user statistics - how many users watch 10 ads+, and a few more parameters that I've deleted for simplicity sake.
Right now with a very similar query I get single counters for every custom event I add - even though it should count how many instances the event has occurred for that specific user.

```
with data as (
        SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp, event_name, app_info.id,geo.country as country,platform,app_info.id as bundle_id,app_info.install_source as ins_source,traffic_source.source as traf_source,traffic_source.name as campaign,
                  UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP('2019-11-01 00:00:00')) AS start_day,
                  3600*1000*1000*24 AS one_day_micros
                FROM `api-table.analytics_random.events_*`
                WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN '20191101' AND '20191215'
              ),
              cohort_info as (
                select user_pseudo_id,bundle_id
                from data
                group by 1,2
              ),
              day_0_users as (
                SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id,
                FROM data
                WHERE event_name = 'first_open'
                  AND event_timestamp BETWEEN start_day AND start_day+(15*one_day_micros)
              ),
              finished_10 as (
                  SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id
                  FROM data
                  WHERE event_name IN( 'ad_finished_10','ads_finished_10')  AND event_timestamp BETWEEN start_day AND start_day+(30*one_day_micros)
              ),
              joined as (
                select
                  cohort_info.user_pseudo_id,
                  cohort_info.bundle_id,
                  count(distinct day_0_users.user_pseudo_id) as day_0_users,
                  count(distinct finished_10.user_pseudo_id) as finished_10_,
                from day_0_users
                left join finished_10 using(user_pseudo_id)
                inner join cohort_info using(user_pseudo_id)
                group by 1,2
              )
              select * from joined
```

I think that my problem is with me selecting distinct user_pseudo_id, where I should count them? The problem is that in the joined subquery I've tried selecting non distinct count values - the result was the same.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to count here? I assume it is: How many times a given user, app_id, event combination occurred in your data?

Comment: how many times for example the event ad_finished_10 occurred

Answer (score 0):

What you are *probably* looking for is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on both subsets with respect to the all-inclusive `data`.

I think something like this can give you your result:

```
with data as (
   SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp, event_name, app_info.id,geo.country as country,platform,app_info.id as bundle_id,app_info.install_source as ins_source,traffic_source.source as traf_source,traffic_source.name as campaign,
      UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP('2019-11-01 00:00:00')) AS start_day,
      3600*1000*1000*24 AS one_day_micros
  FROM `api-table.analytics_random.events_*`
  WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN '20191101' AND '20191215'
),
finished_10 as (
   SELECT distinct user_pseudo_id
   FROM data
   WHERE event_name IN( 'ad_finished_10','ads_finished_10')  
   AND (event_timestamp BETWEEN start_day AND start_day+(30*one_day_micros))
),
day_0_users as (
   SELECT distinct user_pseudo_id,
   FROM data
   WHERE event_name = 'first_open'
   AND (event_timestamp BETWEEN start_day AND start_day+(15*one_day_micros))
)

select 
   d.user_pseudo_id, 
   d.bundle_id, 
   sum(if(f.user_pseudo_id is null, 0, 1)) as ad_finished_10_count,
   sum(if(dz.user_pseudo_id is null, 0, 1)) as day_0_count
from data d
left join finished_10 f on f.user_pseudo_id = d.user_pseudo_id
left join day_0_users dz on dz.user_pseudo_id = d.user_pseudo_id
group by 1,2
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hey, seems that your solutions counts unique users in every event, where it should count the times an event occurred for the specific user that it's grouped by

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. You need to pull event_time (as unique value for every event) and count it instead of counting users.

```
with data as (
   SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp, event_name, app_info.id,geo.country as country,platform,app_info.id as bundle_id,app_info.install_source as ins_source,traffic_source.source as traf_source,traffic_source.name as campaign,
      UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP('2019-11-01 00:00:00')) AS start_day,
      3600*1000*1000*24 AS one_day_micros
  FROM `api-table.analytics_random.events_*`
  WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN '20191101' AND '20191215'
),
finished_10 as (
   SELECT distinct user_pseudo_id
   FROM data
   WHERE event_name IN( 'ad_finished_10','ads_finished_10')  
   AND (event_timestamp BETWEEN start_day AND start_day+(30*one_day_micros))
),
day_0_users as (
   SELECT distinct user_pseudo_id,event_timestamp
   FROM data
   WHERE event_name = 'first_open'
   AND (event_timestamp BETWEEN start_day AND start_day+(15*one_day_micros))
)

select 
   d.user_pseudo_id, 
   d.bundle_id, 
   sum(if(f.user_pseudo_idis null, 0, 1)) as ad_finished_10_count,
   sum(if(dz.event_timestamp is null, 0, 1)) as day_0_count
from data d
left join finished_10 f on f.user_pseudo_id = d.user_pseudo_id
left join day_0_users dz on dz.user_pseudo_id = d.user_pseudo_id
group by 1,2
```

Comment: Hey, seems that this is not it. The finished_10 event shouldn't have more than 1 occurrence per user - as the firebase event analyzer also indicates. There are other events that have multiple occurrences for each user, but the finished_10 isn't one of them

Comment: made small update. maybe now  it works. If not I would need some more input.